# Does BitLocker encrypt in-place?

Tags: windows-10, disk-encryption, bitlocker

I can't find explicit documentation on this anywhere: Is **BitLocker** doing an in-place encryption?

As to, I can actually encrypt my whole running system, with the Windows partition itself, without having to install Windows from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in place. It resume if you have to close the computer too.

You can see the high level step there; https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-encrypt-system-partition-bitlocker-windows-7-windows-8